NHST from the Bayesian point of view
In How to become a Bayesian in eight easy steps, it is stated

Frequentist statistics only allow for statements to be made about P(data | theory). Assuming the theory is correct, the probability of observing the obtained (or more extreme) data is evaluated. Dienes argues that often the probability of the data assuming a theory is correct is not the probability the researcher is interested in. What
researchers typically want to know is P(theory | data): Given that the data were those obtained, what is the probability that the theory is correct?

My question is : from the Bayesian point of view, what is the value of answers given by NHST (statements about p(data|theory)  )?
Does it give an answer to the wrong question? Is it of limited value, or completely useless?

I lost you by the second paragraph, because usually "what is of interest to the researcher" is decidedly not the null hypothesis.  Thus I suspect your questions might be best answered by reviewing the logic and principles of NHSTs.

"The posterior probability of the null hypothesis, Bayesians argue, is precisely what is of interest to the researcher." Not convinced. The empirical evidence seems to suggest that scientist-researchers have little interest in posterior probabilities!

Just a reminder that Bayesians tend to have reservations about point null hypotheses, see Jeffreys-Lindley paradox.

@whuber I have corrected the post

Some relevant posts:Do frequentists and Bayesians use different hypothesis tests?, Examples of Bayesian and frequentist approach giving different answers, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC10600289/

@GrahamBornholt you couldn't be more incorrect.  Time after time when researchers are asked what they want, what amounts to Bayesian probabilities is the answer. I've never heard one research say she had an interest in the probability of data being more surprising than those observed given an unknowable assumption.

@FrankHarrell I did not discuss p-values. Whatever level of interest researchers have in probabilities, there is no evidence that posterior probabilities would satisfy their interest.

See Gelman's blog Bayesians are frequentists

For an extended, Bayesian broadside against frequentism, attempting to pick up where E.T. Jaynes left off, see Aubrey Clayton's recent book Bernoulli's Fallacy:
https://cup.columbia.edu/book/bernoullis-fallacy/9780231199957

If you're asking about "people who identify strongly as Bayesians," I'm sure you've seen that some individual Bayesians do believe NHST is mostly useless :-)
But if you're asking about "Bayesian methodology," statements about P(data|theory) are merely answers to a different question. There doesn't need to be a value judgment -- classical questions just aren't addressed by Bayesian methods and vice versa, just like a nail isn't addressed by a screwdriver or a screw isn't addressed by a hammer.
Classical statements about P(data|theory) deliberately focus on sampling variation, separating it out from other sources of uncertainty. They address questions that should be noncontroversial when a scientist is planning or reporting properties of their study design. My kitchen scale is accurate to within 1 gram, while my bathroom scale is only accurate to within 1 pound... Likewise with a scientific study design: Can we expect it to give a sample mean within 1 gram of the population mean, or only within 1 pound of the population mean?
Bayesian statements about P(theory|data,prior) deliberately combine sampling variation with your prior beliefs about the theory into new posterior beliefs. They should be noncontroversial when you've sincerely believed a prior, and then you saw new data: how should you update your prior into a posterior? You might use that posterior to report a credible interval, for instance letting the rest of us know whether your posterior uncertainty about the mean is on the order of grams or pounds. But because you've averaged over a prior, this uncertainty is not trying to quantify the sampling variation alone, like P(data|theory) did. So, P(data|theory) is simply tackling a different question than finding a posterior.
The same person might care about both questions at different moments, of course.

When I'm pondering whether the study is precise / powerful enough, I might wear my Classical hat and look at P(data|theory). Then I won't average over a prior, if it's a distraction from my current question.
Or when I'm up against a deadline and have to make a decision / take an action based on the currently-available information, I might wear my Bayesian hat. Then I just need to pin down my prior, get a posterior, and use it to make my decision, regardless of whether or not the sampling variation is as low as I'd like it to be, so I won't be looking at P(data|theory) alone.


For a brief example of "how P(data|theory) answers whether the study is powerful enough", consider a one-sample Normal-based test of $H_0: \mu=\mu_0$ vs $H_A: \mu \neq \mu_0$. With Normally-distributed data, the power at a specific sample size $n$, alternative $\mu_A$, assumed standard deviation $\sigma$, and standard significance level $\alpha=0.05$ is given by
$$P\left(\left|(\bar{x}-\mu_0)/SE\right| > 1.96 | \mu=\mu_A,\sigma\right)$$
where $SE=\sigma/\sqrt{n}$. In other words, "For samples of size $n$, how often will we reject $H_0$, if the true mean is $\mu_A$ and true SD is $\sigma$?" is equivalent to "For samples of size $n$, how often will we obtain a sample in which $\bar{x}$ falls at least 1.96 $SE$'s away from $\mu_0$, if the true mean is $\mu_A$ and true SD is $\sigma$?" which is a specific instance of P(data|theory).
The Bayesian might say "I'm just not going to try answering that question. The question I'd prefer to ask is $P(\mu=\mu_A|data)$. I've got a prior on $\mu$ and $\sigma$ already, and I'm going to update it with the data in order to answer my question instead of yours. Or if I still have to choose a sample size, I'll choose $n$ big enough to ensure my posterior has a desired level of precision on average across my prior."
The Frequentist might respond "Go ahead. But I am not trying to ask what to believe after averaging across the prior. I am trying to ask what to expect at specific combinations of $n$, $\mu_A$, and $\sigma$. That way, I can choose $n$ large enough to have high power for ruling out $\mu_0$ even if $|\mu_A-\mu_0|$ is as small as such-and-such. I'll plan for the worst case, not for the average case."

Finally, one more perspective: If you and your research community all agree on the same prior, the Bayesian can often get away with a smaller $n$ than the Frequentist can, because the prior is often mathematically equivalent to having a few extra observations. In this sense, the Bayesian asks "What's the precision of our estimate if we consider earlier data as well as the current study?" Meanwhile, the Frequentist asks "What's the precision of our estimate just from this current study?" Both questions can be useful; neither strictly dominates the other.

Sorry for the ignorance, perhaps you have a link to a resource which explains how P(data|theory) answers whether the study is powerful enough?

@Sam No problem. I've added a bit more to the answer -- does this help address your comment?

As your last paragraph, see Deconstructing Andrew Gelman: “A Bayesian wants everybody else to be a non-Bayesian.”

@kjetilbhalvorsen Hah, that's excellent. I had not seen that.

You have posted about the value of p(data|H1), do you think there also might be value to p(data|H0) from the Bayesian point of view?

@Sam In the standard Bayesian machinery, it's not really valued -- neither p(data|H1) nor p(data|H0) are posteriors, so they're not something a Bayesian interprets directly.

On the other hand, in practice some Bayesians (like Andrew Gelman) do advocate for model checking by using posterior predictive checks that are close to this in spirit: simulate new data from p(newdata | H0, olddata) and see whether the new/simulated data looks similar to the real data, to help you decide whether your current model H0 is "good enough" or if you need to fit a larger, more complex model to capture some interesting data feature that's missing from your current simulated data.

My understanding is that orthodox Bayesians aren't "supposed" to check models in this way; it's more coherent to start with the largest model you can think of whose parameters have any nonzero prior support, then fit it once, and make decisions based on the posterior. But in practice, if you fit too large of a model to a finite dataset, any information in the data itself will be diffused across too many parameters and you'll basically be left with a posterior almost identical to your prior. So it's often pragmatic to choose a reasonably small "good enough" model... like Frequentists do.

As is sometimes the case, the "Bayesian" perspective in the paragraph quoted is not quite accurate concerning the frequentist approach. The probability of the data given the theory is the likelihood, not a p-value. Likelihoods are more directly used in Bayesian approaches than they are by frequentists. Even there they never offer utility as standalone values because they only have evidential meaning as a ratio between the likelihoods of two different parameter values ("theories" [sic]).
Anyone who wishes to criticise "NHST" should know better what it is, and most importantly what it isn't!
Do scientist want to know the probability of their theories given the data? Probably not as often as might be assumed. In my experience as a biological scientist with a statistical bent I do not recall ever being asked about how to calculate "P(theory|data)". Furthermore, any discussion of what "researchers want" should make a clear contrast between statistical hypotheses and scientific hypotheses and theories. Statistical approaches give inferences concerning statistical models, whereas scientific theories concern the real world. I have written about these things here and suggest that you and the authors of the quoted paragraph have a look.
[Yes, this is a mixture of comment and rant. It's too long for a comment and so I made it an answer that fails to answer a valid question.]

Have to strongly disagree with the last paragraph, after 5 decades of working with biomedical scientists of all types.  But I wouldn't say it's the probability that a point theory is correct; what they ask for is the chance an unknown true effect is in a certain direction most of the time.

@FrankHarrell I'm not sure that I understand your point. If scientists want "the chance an unknown true effect is in a certain direction" then  surely they are not asking for the probability of theories. That would mean that you agree with the start of the last paragraph even if you would have written it differently.

(+1) Very informative. Cox(1958) is a great early reference for the distinction between statistical inference and scientific inference.

@GrahamBornholt Thanks for that reference. I'll look at it. I'm sad to say that it was not until towards the end of my career as a pharmacologist that I finally worked out the role of statistical analysis in scientific inference. I found the book Statistics as Principled Argument by RP Abelson to be very enlightening.

Hi Michael - I'm splitting hairs but an example of a theory is "this drug lowers blood pressure".  Then the investigator wants Pr(theory is correct | data, prior knowledge) = Pr(difference in means between treatment groups < 0 | data, prior).

@FrankHarrell Aha! Your Pr(theory is correct | data, prior knowledge) is the posterior, and that is not the same as the likelihood that I mentioned in the paragraph. Your zeal for all things Bayesian may have led you to read too superficially. (What do you think of the rest of that paragraph? Surely it is pretty close to calling for consideration of prior information... ) Read it again.

Yes looks good.

From a bayesian perspective, the probability of a given null hypothesis is given by:
$$
P(H_0 | D) = \frac{P(D|H_0)P(H_0)}{P(D)}
$$
where $P(D|H_0)$ is the p-value obtained under your null hypothesis, $P(H_0)$ the prior probability of your null hypothesis and $P(D)$ the marginal of the data.
In other words $P(D|H_0)$ can be seen as an equivalent of the data likelihood when computing the posterior of some parameters. The probability of a given null hypothesis is proportional to the p-value under your null model weighted by the prior of this hypothesis. Intuitively, more data you have, less the prior will shrink your posterior. Similarly, less data you have more your posterior will be driven by your prior.
Except under certain circumstances, there is not equivalence between p-value and bayesian interpretation of hypothesis testing. However, the p-value is used to compute some posteriors from the information provided by the data.

Thank you for the mathematical formalism. My question is : what is the value of p(D|H0)given that it is not weighted by the prior to compute the hypothesis (like done in NHST)? In other words, what is the value of an NHST test from a Bayesian pov? Does it give an answer to the wrong question? Is it completely useless? (Added that to the OP)

Hi @Sam, I am not sure what you mean by "what is the value of an NHST test from a Bayesian pov". Did you ask what is the equivalence of NHST from a Bayesian perspective ?

From the standpoint of this Bayesian there is no value in NHST except possible with an existence hypothesis such as "extra sensory perception exists".  Showing evidence that someone can guess which card I'm holding better than chance would be of interest.  Unfortunately experiments have only shown that those claiming to have ESP guess worse than chance ...

@MangnierLoïc No, the value of an NHST test of view is not its Bayesian equivalent. Rather, I am asking for a value judgement from the Bayesian pov. In other words, what is the benefit of an NHST test.
